# Manipulate the JSON returned from postForObject

Tags: java, firebase, rest, firebase-authentication

I was wondering if there's a way to manipulate the JSON return from the method *postForObject* of the class *RestTemplate*. I read on an old question about the class *JSONObject* but I noticed that has been replaced by *JsonObject* and I don't if it works exactly in the same way. 
Here's my method:

```
public void sendEmail() throws FirebaseAuthException {
    Body body = new Body(firebase.createCustomToken("username"), true);
    RestTemplate t = new RestTemplate();
    Object response = t.postForObject(
            "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=[API_KEY]", 
            body, Object.class);
}
```

The `firebase.createCustomToken("username")` method is a method that I use to return a custom token for a user. The firebase object is an object of the class `FireBaseService` in which I wrote all the useful methods to work with FireBase.
I passed as body of the POST method a *String* and a *boolean*. Everything works good but I don't know how to get the value of a certain JSON field. The value of `response` is:

```
{
  "idToken": "[ID_TOKEN]",
  "refreshToken": "[REFRESH_TOKEN]",
  "expiresIn": "3600"
}
```

The REST API call I'm doing is this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-verify-custom-token.
How can I get the value of the field `idToken`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) response;
String token = json.getString("refreshToken");
```

Comment: `JSONObject` is deprecated in Java 11, which is the version i'm currently using.